# Error during app compilation (visual studio)

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

When I test my `cordova` app created in visual studio with the `Ripple Simulator` it works perfectly, but once I try to build it for my android device, it displays this error:

```
Errore  BLD10205    [Error: Please install Android target: "android-22". 
Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: C:\Program\ Files\ 
(x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.BAT You will require: 1. "SDK 
Platform" for android-22 2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest) 3. 
"Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)] Command finished with error code 2: cmd 
/s /c ""C:\Users\Giulia\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\cordova\b
uild.bat" --release "--buildConfig=C:\Users\Giulia\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\build.json"" ERROR building 
one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2   
BlankCordovaApp2
```

I cant figure out how to solve it! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `Android SDK Manager`. It should look like this:

[image]

And for you `Android SDK Build-tools`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, now it works, but there's another error: `The Android packages must be signed when you debug with the version type configuration. To configure the Android signature , follow the instructions in http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613579`

Comment: Seems like you want to build a release app? How do you try to deploy your app? With `cordova run android`?

Comment: Maybe i did something wrong, i just want to try my app on my smartphone. I'm not sure what are you asking me about deploy, but im doing everything with VS2015

Comment: I am not using visual studio. But what I do is: Plug in your device. In a `CLI` check if your device is recognized with `adb devices`. It should list your plugged-in device. Try to deploy (run) your app from your project root directory with `cordova build android` and `cordova run android`

Comment: Are you building for Debug or Release?